# 300ms click delay not disabled in full screen mode (iOS safari)

Tags: ios, ipad, viewport, meta-tags

I'm creating a web app that needs to be displayed in full screen mode on an ipad. I also need to remove the 300ms click delay for the app to perform responsively. To do this I've added the following metatags to the header:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=0">
```

Full screen mode is activated when I add the website to my home screen (Safari, Share->Add To Home Screen).

The issue I'm running into is that when I view the web app in Safari, the 300ms click delay is removed, however, in full screen mode (when opening the app via the home screen icon), the 300ms click delay persists.

As a very simple example, here is a codepen with 2 radio buttons with the meta tags set as I mentioned above:

http://codepen.io/cgat/full/ZBwYyW/

If you open this pen in mobile Safari and add to the home screen, you'll see the delay in radio clicks.

I'm testing with an ipad air.

Comment: After extensive searching, I'm pretty sure there is no work around, at least for iOS 10. The home screen web app is run in a UIWebview layer, which doesn't response to metatags as expected. Scrolling is another issue. Swiped scroll events (where the scroll continues while the user is no longer touching the device) only trigger at the tail of the scroll (when it stops)

Comment: The fact that this question is 5 years old is so interesting. Does it really mean that almost nobody adds websites to their home screens? Maybe because they already anticipate that it won't look and feel like an app anyways? I'd really love if Apple solved this. But incentives aren't aligned I guess?